# Flask passing variables through routes

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

So i have an issue where I am using the flask route to edit a existing tab in a project of mine. What should happen is that my project store two things user and tabs. I have several tabs that are in my database and i want to create edit functionality to it. So i am creating and edit route that will pass the users id and tab id that is being editied. What should happen is that the tabs amount and description that is being edited will appear in the input box for me to edit. it should then change that tab in the database and return to the page that shows all of the tables with the edit.

What is happening is that no matter what tab i click on it shows the first tabs information in the input box and when i submit to edit add and commit the change to the database, it is added a new tab and giving it the values that changed. I will insert 3 peices of code.

** i do have all of the correct sqlalchemy informaiton imported

the first piece of code is the database

```
class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = Column(String(16), nullable = False, unique = True, index = True)

class Tab_Event(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tab_event'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    description = Column(String(200))
    amount = Column(String(10))#may be changed to a float or decimal value later on during development
    user_id = Column(Integer(10), ForeignKey('users.id'))
    users = relationship(Users)
```

The following section of code is the routes that are being used

```
@app.route('/user/<int:user_id>')
def DisplayUsers(user_id):
    user = session.query(Users).filter_by(id = user_id).one()
    items = session.query(Tab_Event).filter_by(user_id = user.id)
    return render_template('viewTabs.html', user = user, items = items)

@app.route('/newtab/<int:user_id>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def AddNewTab(user_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        newTab = Tab_Event(amount = request.form['amount'], description = request.form['description'], user_id = user_id)
        session.add(newTab)
        session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('DisplayUsers', user_id = user_id))
    return render_template('createTab.html', user_id = user_id)

@app.route('/edit/<int:user_id>/<int:tab_id>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def EditTabEvent(user_id, tab_id):
    editTab = session.query(Tab_Event).filter_by(id = user_id).one()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['name']:
            editTab.name = request.form['amount']
        if request.form['description']:
            editTab.description = request.form['description']
        session.add(editTab)
        session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('DisplayUsers', user_id = user_id))
    else:
        return render_template('editTab.html', user_id = user_id, tab_id = tab_id, item = editTab)
```

The last piece of code is the html document that i am using to edit

```
<html>
  <body>

    <h1>This page is where new users are made</h1>
    <form action="{{url_for('AddNewTab', user_id = user_id, tab_id = item.id)}}" method="POST">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Username</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Amount</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="amount", value="{{item.amount}}"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Description</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="description", value="{{item.description}}"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="Radio">Personal</td>
          <td><input type="Radio">Business</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="submit" value="Edit Tab"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

the repository that has these files is below:
vagrant >> PayUp >> all of the files for this project to run on local machine
https://github.com/omar-jandali/Udacity-Tournament/tree/master/vagrant/PayUp

Comment: see SQL query in `EditTabEvent` - you don't use `tab_id` to get data so you always get first tab.

Comment: and see your model `Tab_Event` -`id` is not user id (there is `user_id` too) but in query you use `id=user_id` so it should be `id=tab_id`

Comment: thank you that fixed the problem right away. i had a feeling it was with one of the variables that i set.

Comment: So it is leading the correct information but when i submit the form it is not making changes to the database and the values are not changing. can you help me with that. I think it is in the edit route def when i am setting the new values and commiting and i tried a few things but no luck.. @furas

Comment: you use `session.add(editTab)` so probably new values are added as new row in database (of course with new unique ID). Remove this if you want update oryginal row.

Comment: BTW: use some database viewer to see what you have in database now.

Comment: Yeah when i looked at it, the values are being added but it is not displaying them or replacing them i have like 3 copes of the same entry with different dollar amounts. how come it is not replaceing. when i took away the add and commit, it is not doing anything... @furas

Comment: I actually checked to see what the database is populated with and none of the changes are commiting and the data is not getting updated --- but when i get rid of the session.add(editeTab), i am getting the same result @furas

Comment: in `editTab.html` you have `url_for('AddNewTab'` so you send form to wrong function - it has to be `url_for('EditTabEvent'`